# how to make web2py installation for a website?

Tags: python, web2py, vs-web-site-project

I want to install a web2py app to my website.

what are the ways to install a web2py application to my website?

Comment: web2py is a framework that needs some installation on server, so the application must be supported. Could you specify your question? Do you want to make a sort of an applet or something like that?

Comment: yea i am having my own doamin name which hosted on 000webhost. now i need to make my website with web2py. please explain me the ways

Comment: You need some hosting that supports python on the web server, 000webhost supports it on premium accounts so once you sign for one you should read the docs of the service provider.

IMHO would be better for you a VPS than a webhosting service, since there is no big difference on the price but a VPS has a better performance, take a look on DigitalOcean.

Comment: yeah, how to implement it in server.. should I install the web2py in server

Answer (score 2):

In the official book you find a lot of useful information how to set up and alter the web2py application. Maybe the deployment chapter is a good resource.

[Read about deployment recipes in the web2py book](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes).

Personally I like `pythonanywhere` - where you can make free installations for testing your app. There is also a part about the deployment for `pythonanywhere` in the book:

[web2py deployment on pythonanywhere](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#Deploying-on-PythonAnywhere).

Comment: @XaviLópez Thanks for the hint. I added some context.

Answer (score 1):

I have summarized my recipe at http://www.icd10doc.com/init/recipes/DeployWeb2PyPythonAnywhere

Hope it helps